# how to get global variables while testing using phpunit-selenium

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-ide

I have my custom function testfunction_phpbb() inside functions.php (phpbb) and i want to test it.

```
function testfunction_phpbb()
{
global $user
...
...
...
//if valid user
return 1;
//else
return 0
}
```

when i execute the following test case i find that always $user is empty (i dont get the global context). The question is when i test a function inside a phpbb,drupal,joomla etc.. how do i get the context when testing through phpunit+selenium?

```php
<?php
require_once './includes/functions.php';
class globaltest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
protected function setUp()
{
$this->setBrowser("*chrome");
$this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/");
}
public function testMyTestCase()
{
$this->open("/");
$this->click("link=phpBB3");
$this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
$this->click("link=Login");
$this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
$this->type("id=username", "admin");
$this->type("id=password", "admin123");
$this->click("name=login");
$this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
$returnvalue = testfunction_phpbb();
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals('1',$returnvalue);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Global variables break unit tests, as you have discovered. For this reason, they are a bad idea and the generally accepted solutions are either:

- Rewrite your code to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), so that the $user variable is passed in as a parameter (you can then pass in a fake one as part of the test)
- Use [PHPUnit's support for backing up and mocking the global variables](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/797-Global-Variables-and-PHPUnit.html).

I would generally go for the dependency injection approach as you'll have a far easier time of it. If you're using a framework however, you may be stuck with the globals so the second option is your best bet.